# Display HTML 5 Telephone number link in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have the following question:

I would like to have a click-able telephone-number on my HTML5 Webpage.
Normally I would simply use

```
<a href="tel: +123456789"> 123456789 </a>
```

But in my case, I get the number from a database and access the number lime this.

By now the code line looks like this:

```
<a href=""> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AD_Tel)</a>
```

So how do I get the `href` to call the number, if it isn't a fixed number?

If something is unclear, please leave a comment and I will add missing information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
<a href="tel:+@item.AD_Tel">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AD_Tel)</a>
```

**Update:**

Creating an HtmlHelper extension method will allow this to be used your views like this:

```
 @Html.TelephoneLink("00000000000")
```

or

```
  @Html.TelephoneLink(item.AD_Tel)
```

Extension code:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString TelephoneLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string telephoneNumber)
    {
        var tb = new TagBuilder("a");
        tb.Attributes.Add("href", string.Format("tel:+{0}", telephoneNumber));
        tb.SetInnerText(telephoneNumber);
        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on answer from hutchonoid :

```
    public static MvcHtmlString TelephoneLinkFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var data = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);            
        var tb = new TagBuilder("a");
        tb.Attributes.Add("href", string.Format("tel:+{0}", data.Model));
        tb.SetInnerText("" + data.Model);
        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString());
    }
```

Usage : `@Html.TelephoneLinkFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)`

Answer (score 1):

Extending on the answer by @john-marston, which extends upon the one by @Hutchonoid...

the helper can be improved by running the number through a regex first. This strips it of any `+`, `(`, `)`, `-` or space, which are commonly added to phone numbers. Once down to raw digits the + can be added, and we have also ensured it's the only one now.

```
var regEx = new Regex("[^0-9]");
var phoneNumber = regEx.Replace(data.Model.ToString(), "");
tb.Attributes.Add("href", $"tel:+{phoneNumber}");
```

Also, here's a **.NET Core version**

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static IHtmlContent TelephoneLinkFor<TModel, TValue>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var data = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData, helper.MetadataProvider);
            var tb = new TagBuilder("a");
            var regEx = new Regex("[^0-9]");
            var phoneNumber = regEx.Replace(data.Model.ToString(), "");
            tb.Attributes.Add("href", $"tel:+{phoneNumber}");
            tb.InnerHtml.Append("" + data.Model);

            var stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            tb.WriteTo(stringWriter, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            var tagAsString = stringWriter.ToString();
            return new HtmlContentBuilder().SetHtmlContent(tagAsString);
        }
    }
}
```

Still implemented with `@Html.TelephoneLinkFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the phonenumber in a variable first and put it in the href="HERE"??

Comment: Sorry that was about all info I can give... Html knowledge is not the best... I'll try to give you an answer but it'll take some time ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AD_Tel)"> 123456789 </a>
```

Comment: This does not work, because now it is considered as a link, not a number.