# Trying to generate clickable telephone link in .net Core 5 Razor pages project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, extension-methods, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm currently generating employee list and Contacts list pages and need to have the telephone numbers be formated to

```
 <a href="tel: +123456789"> 123456789 </a>
```

I could do this manually but considering this will be reoccurring across the site I figured an HTML Extension method would be the best way to implement it.

I found this link [Display HTML 5 Telephone number link in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242096/display-html-5-telephone-number-link-in-razor)

But the two solutions offered don't compile and I'm having trouble debugging them.

ExpressionMetadataProvider gives the error "non-accessible to protection level." Would love guidance on what I'm missing or if their is a better way to do this in .net core 5

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with custom tag helper:

```
public class TelTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string TelNum { get; set; }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "a";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", "tel: +" + TelNum);
        output.Content.SetContent(TelNum);
    }
}
```

Add the addTagHelper directive to the Views/_ViewImports.cshtml file:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, YourProjectName
```

Then in the view, you can use it like this:

```
<tel tel-num="123456789"></tel>
```

The render html:

[image]

For more details, refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-3.1).